# Android menu item click option

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

There are 3 Activities in my project namely Main Activity, Activity1 and Activity2. And also I added a navigation drawer to my project. I want to switch between activities when I click Home, Videos, ContactUs menu items respectively. But I have no idea about how to do that.

```
int id = item.getItemId();

    //Home menu item is clicked
    if (id == R.id.home){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

I tested this code, but it failed.

Comment: Android documentation is really useful, try: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html. If you still have issues then ask a question AFTER you have read, understood, debugged etc without success...

Comment: You can't do `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);` .Just from `MainActivity` to `MainActivity`.

Comment: I can't even switch between other activities

Comment: In your fourth line add another Activity. Don't use same activity.

Comment: 'int id = item.getItemId();

    //Home menu item is clicked
    if (id == R.id.home){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
        Activity2.this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }'

Doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and the logcat of any error you have

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add both activities to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,SecondClass.class);
startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy this code and paste it in your respective activity.

1. Copy this in `onNavigationItemSelected()` in `MainActivity.class`

   ```
               int id = item.getItemId();            
               if (id == R.id.Home) {                    
               } else if (id == R.id.Videos) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity1.class);
                   startActivity(intent);            
               } else if (id == R.id.ContactUs) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                   startActivity(intent); }
   ```
2. Copy this in `onNavigationItemSelected()` in `Activity1.class`

   ```
                   int id = item.getItemId();            
                   if (id == R.id.Home) {  
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,MainActivity.class);       
                       startActivity(intent);           
                   } else if (id == R.id.Videos) {    
                   } else if (id == R.id.ContactUs) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                       startActivity(intent); }
   ```
3. Copy this in `onNavigationItemSelected()` in `Activity2.class`

   ```
                  int id = item.getItemId();            
                  if (id == R.id.Home) {  
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this,MainActivity.class);       
                      startActivity(intent);           
                  } else if (id == R.id.Videos) {   
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity1.class);
                      startActivity(intent); 
                  } else if (id == R.id.ContactUs) {
                  }
   ```

Finally, as you can't go to the same activity, you can reload/refresh it by using

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

You can now reload the activity by inserting above two lines in the blank if/else if of respective activity as in my code like Home is empty in MainActivity.class.
I didn't write the above two lines and left one `id==?` empty because leaving empty won't do anything.

Comment: Navigation drawer typically changes Fragments, not Activities

Comment: It depends on the user whether he's using fragments or activities. I've used this code in my sample project on a large scale and it works fine.